# Passing Object/Reference data types between Activities using the Parcelable interface

Tags: android

I have an object `mPlusClient` of type `PlusClient` and I want to pass this object (as the same object) between two activities.

That is from Activity A where it is created to Activity B.  I am not sure how to go about this.

All the examples I have seen so far on StackOverflow focus on primitive types.

Comment: You can refer to my tutorial, http://pcode.petehouston.com/2014/0103227/pass-complex-object-structure-intent/

Answer (score 0):

check this [tutorial](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/) out. It describes how to implement `Parcelable` then shows you how to pass it between `Activity`s via an `Intent`'s `putExtra(String, Parcelable)`.

Comment: This is still a tutorial on `primitive types`.Am looking for a way to pass references.